# JavaScript: How do you use Array.prototype.filter() on arrays that contain objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was arranging a file tree and I only wanted to show file/folder name that don't have "." at the start of their names. But I always get the same array after I filter it. What do I do?

So here what have I tried:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: ".hidden",
    size: "14"
  },
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: ".secret",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
];
arr.filter(obj => {
  // charCode of "." is 46
  if(obj.name.charCodeOf(0) !== 46) {
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Expexted Console:

```
[
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
]
```

Reality:

```
[
  {
    name: ".hidden",
    size: "14"
  },
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: ".secret",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
]
```

Comment: 1. simply use `if (obj.name.startsWith("."))` 2. `filter()` doesn't change the array in place, it returns a filtered array. You need `arr = arr.filter(({ name }) => !name.startsWidth("."));`

Comment: try arr = arr.filter

Comment: And BTW, it's not `charCodeOf`, it's `charCodeAt`.

Comment: As an aside, your if else block is completely redundant. You can simply use `return condition;`

Comment: Could you use  chartCodeAt(0) as I mentioned in my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try **chartCodeAt(0)** instead

```
let arr = [
  {
    name: ".hidden",
    size: "14"
  },
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: ".secret",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
];
arr = arr.filter(obj => {
  // charCode of "." is 46
  if(obj.name.charCodeAt(0) !== 46) {
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) for this scenario. Also, you are returning the original `arr` in the console log, but `filter()` does not modify the original array. It returns a new modified array which actually you need to put in the console log.

```js
const arr = [{name:".hidden",size:"14"},{name:"View",size:"12"},{name:".secret",size:"12"},{name:"Public",size:"11"}];

var newArr = arr.filter(({name}) => name.startsWith("."));
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Note: `startsWith` is not supported in IE11 if you require broad browser support, you would need a polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: ".hidden",
    size: "14"
  },
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: ".secret",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
];

const filteredArray = arr.filter(obj => !obj.name.startsWith("."));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple issues:

1. You should use `indexOf` to check for the dot in the first position of the string. (Better browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=indexOf)
2. The array filter returns a new array with your filtered results.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: ".hidden",
    size: "14"
  },
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: ".secret",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
];
const newArray = arr.filter(obj => obj.name.indexOf(".") === 0);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest way

```
const result = arr.filter(obj => !obj.name.startsWith('.'));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. What if the folder is named `My.Folder`? It has to be the first character.

Comment: My bad. Updated the ans.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an ideal solution for your issue:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: ".hidden",
    size: "14"
  },
  {
    name: "View",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: ".secret",
    size: "12"
  },
  {
    name: "Public",
    size: "11"
  }
];

const result = arr.filter(obj => !obj.name.startsWith("."));

console.log(result);
```